# Nested tables with no borders aligned to top

Tags: html, css

I want to align nested tables to top. But the mismatch in lines shows that it is not the case.
I think I eliminated all border size, padding, spacing from tables, but still there is something that prevents it from true top alignment.

```
display:inline-table;
vertical-align:top;
border-style: dotted;
border-width: 0px;
border-spacing: 0px; /* Removes the cell spacing via CSS */
border-collapse: collapse;  /* no double border where cells touch */
padding: 0px;
```

[image]

MWE:
https://jsfiddle.net/n89bsc4g/

Comment: Those cells are both the same height B & C are the same height. There is some whitespace there... but I am unsure of how to get rid of it. Take a look at this fiddle. Makes it a little easier to spot the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/n89bsc4g/1/

Comment: B-B1 table and C-C1 table do not have the same markup- See them aligned when I made the markups similar: https://jsfiddle.net/n8bube8a/

Answer (score 0):

[Reset Css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) at the beginning of writing css!

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

checkout the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n89bsc4g/3/)